# Hibernate 5.2.11 - Multiple simultaneously Featch.Eager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class witch has 4 Lists with a @*toMany annotation:

```
    public class Component {

            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "component", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = ComponentHistoric.class)
            //@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
            @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
            private List<ComponentHistoric> componentHistoricList;

            @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Organization.class)
            @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
            private List<Organization> organizations;

            @OneToMany(targetEntity = ComponentPerson.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
            private List<ComponentPerson> componentPeople;

            @OneToMany(targetEntity = ComponentLink.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
            @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
            private List<ComponentLink> componentLinks;
    }
```

It is not possible to use a `Set<>` instead of the `Lists`. When I use `featch = Featch.Eager`. I get the exception (Number 1). The currently version above I get the exception (Number 2).

> Exception (Number 1): org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

-

> Exception (Number 2): org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.ComponentHistoric.componentHistoricVersion, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
```

to the `xxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.ComponentHistoric.componentHistoricVersion`

A better way is always use lazy loading and load necessary association with `Hibernate.initialize()`, `join fetch` etc., because you will not be able to disable  eagerly loading of associations with `@LazyCollection`.

Answer (score 2):

Exception Number 1:

This is a limitation of Hibernate that does not support more than one eager loaded List in an entity.

Exception Number 2:

When your list is accessed outside the transaction boundary you get this exception. So you must initialize this collection before you use it.

There are many option to do so:

- Call the getter or iterator on the collection
- Use Hibernate.initialize() and pass the collection as parameter
- Use join fetch in a query when loading the entities with a query